# Asynchronous Drools Expert rule evaluation

Tags: drools

I have situation where the set of rules I am writing will be invoked via a REST service in an asynchronous manner via JMS message queues. Essentially what is happening is that from the GUI, a ticket is raised which has a unique ticket id value. For this ticket, a particular rule evaluation has to be done. Once this rule evaluation is done, the result of the evaluation has to be linked to this particular ticket via the ticket id. My question is what is the best way to achieve this linkage between a ticket id and the result of the rule evaluation in my DRL files? Do I have a Ticket fact type in every condition of every rule? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a Ticket fact with its unique id seems to be a good solution. You don't have to refer to it in all your rules (only if the rules depends on it). Then, you can check all the facts remaining in your working memory and get the ticket fact with its id after all your rules have been run.

Comment: +1 @zenbeni that seems good as it confirms my initial thoughts. For each ticket, there will be a separate rule invocation and so a separate knowledge session. Each knowledge session will have the unique id for that ticket and so after the rule evaluation I will be able to link it with the respective ticket.